# Why the variable is cut while reading a file?

Tags: bash, file

This is my code to read a file line by line:

```
IFS=$'\n'
myfile="$1"
i=0
while read line; do
    echo "Line # $i: '$line'"
    let i++
done < "$myfile"
```

This is the file passed as parameter

```
Hello
stack
overflow
friends
```

I execute it like this: `test.sh input.txt` and I get this result:

```
'ine # 0: 'Hello
'ine # 1: 'stack
'ine # 2: 'overflow
'ine # 3: 'friends
```

As you see, The fisrt character is replaced by a quote. And the quote of the final of the line does not appear. Whats going on here? I can't see the mistake? Any idea?

Comment: What OS? It works fine w/o chopping for me on OSX. Maybe an issue with the `IFS` interpretation. Did you try without that line?

Comment: It might have to do with the single quotes around $line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have `\r` before end of line in your input file.

You can test same by using:

```
cat -vte file
```

This will show `^M$` in the end of file has dos carriage return `\r`.

You can use this script to read your file correctly:

```
i=1
while IFS=$'\r' read -r line; do
   echo "Line # $i: '$line'"
   let i++
done < "$myfile"
```

OR else convert your file into unix file using:

```
dos2unix file
```

OR If you don't wish to actually save the file stripped off of `\r`, you can also use:

```
while read line; do
........# your code as-is
done < <( tr -d '\r' < "$myfile")
```

Comment: I see an `^M$` at the end of each line using the cat command you posted.

Comment: Right `^M` means `\r`, use my provided script to read the file.

Comment: Using `file` on a text file will tell you about carriage returns in plain text, and also tell you the encoding of the file. (Superior to `cat` IMHO.)

Comment: @anubhava, One little issue: If the last line dosen't finish in `\r` then there is not included in the array... do you have any idea to code a generic solution. Thanks for all. :)

Comment: `tr -d '\r' < "$myfile")` would delete only if it exists, did it not work for you?

Comment: Solved using: `while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do`. Thanks for all.